# Select only elements with a certain CSS attribute using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok I have this code

```
 $("#search-results-all").children(".search-result-item").length;
```

Now, all I want there is to select only the `.search-result-item` elements that is only visible by using css attribute `visibility:visible`. Now how can i make this possible?

P.S. Sorry I don't know what to type in Google so I can start searching.

UPDATE...

well it worked by doing something like this

```
$("#search-results-all").children(".search-result-item:visible").length;
```

thank you for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`:visible Selector`**](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) - Selects all elements that are visible.

```
$("#search-results-all").children(".search-result-item:visible").length;
```

or

```
$("#search-results-all").children(".search-result-item")).is(':visible');
```

Comment: I almost got this in the internet before i saw your answer.. thank you... this is correct and more clean

Comment: `is` returns a boolean, so I don't think you can use `.length` to it http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: "Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout." - Basically, this completely fails to handle the situation the OP is asking about...

Answer (score 2):

The following?

```
$("#search-results-all > .search-result-item").filter(function() {
   return $(this).css('visibility') == 'visible';
}).length;
```

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
$("#search-results-all .search-result-item").filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('visibility') == 'visible';
});
```